# How would mushroom call mycellium home?

Tags: fiction, novel, character-development, plot, science-fiction

I'm wondering for some time.. How would mushrooms fruiting body call it own mycelium? Imagine you're that fruiting body and after releasing your spores you are about to die.

---

[image: mushroom]

Comment: This question is probably better suited to Worldbuilding SE, however it would need to be significantly clarified to be accepted there.

Comment: @ArkensteinXII If OP is asking "what should I name this thing", then that would be off-topic on WorldBuilding. They don't accept naming questions as they're inherently opinion-based.

Comment: @F1Krazy I agree. Honestly, I have no idea what the OP is actually asking.

Answer (score 3):

Truth is, the "mushroom" part of, well, the mushroom, is really only the fruiting body. This is like asking "how would the apple call it's apple tree".

If you want to have mushroom people which looks like mushrooms, you kinda have to forget about the mycelium and chalk it up to creative freedom, because the fruit of the mushroom isn't that big in comparison.

Mushrooms aren't plants. They don't use chlorophyll (well, lichen does, but it's a fungi and an alga teaming up so the fungi still doesn't chlorophyll). They get their energy from decomposing other stuff, which is something the mycelium does - of course.

The "me" of a mushroom should really be the mycelium. Still, to really give you an answer, if I was a mushroom I would refer to my mycelium as my roots.

Then die a gruesome death as I slowly rot alive.

Comment: Hmm..  This now makes me thing of "Mushroom people" being like sentient bee drones, and the mycelium being a non-sentient "queen" that spawns them...

Comment: Mushroom drones is an awesome idea! Mycelium could be sentient or no, depending on the intent of the author, though.